# Saving the exact columns of list in csv in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Have the list of lists "d" like that:

```
[OrderedDict([('id', '1'),
              ('name', 'Jack'),
              ('email', 'jack@email.com'),
 OrderedDict([('id', '2'),
              ('name', 'Ricky'),
              ('email', 'ricky@email.com')]
```

I would like to save the output using csv module but without id line (so with columns Name, Email and their values). Performing like this:

```
path='/..'
fields=['Name','Email']

with open(path, 'w') as f:   
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(fields)
for item in new_d:
    writer.writerow([d[1], d[2]])
```

So it saves me the whole line as a value. How is it possible to get deeper to the level of values of the list and save them properly in csv?

Comment: use a `DictWriter` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv

listOfDicts = [OrderedDict([('id', '1'),
              ('name', 'Jack'),
              ('email', 'jack@email.com')]),
              OrderedDict([('id', '2'),
              ('name', 'Ricky'),
              ('email', 'ricky@email.com')])]
path='someFilename.csv'
fields=['Name','Email']

with open(path, 'w', newline="", encoding="utf8") as f:   
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
    for d in listOfDicts:  # d are your different dictionaries 
        writer.writerow([d['name'], d['email']])
```

creates the file :

```
Name,Email
Jack,jack@email.com
Ricky,ricky@email.com
```

It is important to `open(..)` the file with `newline=""` so you do not get additional newlines into it - `csv` will handle those on its own - you also should specifiy the `encoding` - just to make sure.

I fixed some other indentation and minor parenthesis errors on your example data on the way and provided the needed imports to get a working example.

[csv-writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative can be to use `pandas`:

```
In [4]: data = [OrderedDict([('id', '1'),
   ...:               ('name', 'Jack'),
   ...:               ('email', 'jack@email.com')]),
   ...:         OrderedDict([('id', '2'),
   ...:               ('name', 'Ricky'),
   ...:               ('email', 'ricky@email.com')])]
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)
In [6]: df_ = df.drop('id', axis=1)
In [7]: df_.to_csv('data.csv', header=True, index=False)
In [8]: !head data.csv
name,email
Jack,jack@email.com
Ricky,ricky@email.com
```